# Loss function for CNN segmentation problem that allows for segmentations to 'shift'?

Tags: machine-learning, loss-functions

**In short: I am looking for a loss function that prioritizes the size of the segmentation over the location of the segmentation.**

We are using a modified U-Net to segment an event on two time based inputs. The segmentation starts at the event on input 1 and ends on the event of input 2. The thing that matters in the end for us is the size of the segmentation, so if the event is detected 5 samples prior to the true event, but it is detected 5 samples prior on both inputs, the resulting segmentation would still be perfect. In other words, the correct segmentation, shifted over time, is still correct.

What would be useful loss functions to apply for this particular case?

*Side note: We have though about using a classification network, however a hard requirement is to visualize the event locations, and therefore we decided to stick with segmentation.*